# How to merge the column values of two dataframes based on two unordered columns

Tags: r

I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`. I want to merge the dataframes based on the first two columns. I don't care about the order of the column values as long as they match in both dataframes (for example, 3rd row in df1 matches with the 2nd row of df2 irrespective of the order of `r` and `z`. Similarly, 2nd row of `df1` matches with the 4th row of `df2`). I want to then add the matched V3 column in `df1` and get the result.

df1

```
A  B  C
p  x  1
q  y  3 
r  z  7
```

df2

```
v1  v2  v3
p   x   65
r   z   32
t   u   6
y   q   34
```

result

```
A  B  C  V3
p  x  1  65
q  y  3  34
r  z  7  32
```

Comment: `df2[1:2] <- t(apply(df2[1:2], 1, sort))` then `merge()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First sorting the values in the first two columns of `df2` then `merge()`:

```
df2[1:2] <- t(apply(df2[1:2], 1, sort))
merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("A", "B"), by.y=c("v1", "v2"))
# > merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("A", "B"), by.y=c("v1", "v2"))
#   A B C v3
# 1 p x 1 65
# 2 q y 3 34
# 3 r z 7 32
```

If needed you can do a similar sorting also in `df1`.
Data used:

```
df1 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"A  B  C
p  x  1
q  y  3 
r  z  7")
df2 <- read.table(header=TRUE, text=
"v1  v2  v3
p   x   65
r   z   32
t   u   6
y   q   34 ")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create two new data frames, one from merging on equality between `c('A','B')` and `c('v1','v2')`, then create one from merging on equality between `c('B', 'A')` and `c('v1','v2')`, then rbind them.

```
df1 <- data.frame(A=c('p', 'q', 'r'), B=c('x','y','z'), C=c(1,2,3) )
df2 <- data.frame(v1=c('p',  'r', 't', 'y'), v2=c('x', 'z', 'u', 'q'), v3=c(65,32, 6, 34))


df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = c('A', 'B'), by.y = c('v1', 'v2'))

#The other way around
df4 <- merge(df1, df2, by.x = c('B', 'A'), by.y = c('v1', 'v2'))

#Rearrange df4 columns
df4 <- df4[colnames(df3)] 

df5 <- rbind(df3, df4)
df5

df5
A B C v3
p x 1 65
r z 3 32
q y 2 34
```